# TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, python-3.x, mergesort

I am attempting a mergesort algorithm and I am receiving this type error:

```
Input #1: [3, 1, 2, 5, 9, 6, 7]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Lab1.py", line 24, in <module>
    print('Output #1: ' + mergesort(a))
  File "Lab1.py", line 18, in mergesort
    left = mergesort(lst[:middle])
  File "Lab1.py", line 20, in mergesort
    return merge(left, right)
  File "Lab1.py", line 6, in merge
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

... on this code:

```python
def merge(left, right):
    result = []
    i, j = 0, 0
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i] <= right[j]:
            result.append(left[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(right[j])
            j += 1

def mergesort(lst):
    if len(lst) <= 1:
        return lst
    middle = int(len(lst) / 2)
    left = mergesort(lst[:middle])
    right = mergesort(lst[middle:])
    return merge(left, right)

a = [3,1,2,5,9,6,7]
print 'Input #1: ' + str(a)
print 'Output #1: ' + mergesort(a)
```

Comment: return result from `merge()`

Answer (score 2):

You forget the `return` in your merge function:

```
def merge(left, right):
    result = []
    i, j = 0, 0
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i] <= right[j]:
            result.append(left[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(right[j])
            j += 1
    return result
```

---

Note that this `merge` function is incorrect. If `left` and `right` have different lengths then `result` will *not* contain all the elements of both lists. (because one of the indices, say `i`, will fail the condition of `i < len(left)` when `j` didn't scan the whole `right` list).
This will always happen, since the `while` loop increases only one index at a time, which means that at some point you can have `i = len(left) - 1` and `j = len(right) - 1` but only one of `i` and `j` will be incremented in the next iteration, and one of the two conditions will be `False`, causing the loop to stop.

See:

```
In [2]: mergesort(list(range(17)))
Out[2]: [0]
```

Adding:

```
result.extend(left[i:] or right[j:])
```

before the `return` should fix this problem:

```
In [4]: mergesort(list(range(17)))
Out[4]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

Comment: @GabrielNahmias I'm saying that, the error you get is due to the missing `return result`, but, *even* when adding the `return result` the code is incorrect. I provided *a* possible solution to this last problem. (By the way, I didn't test the code a lot, except with 2-3 inputs, so there may still be some error sneaking around. If you have other problems add a comment here, or update your question with the relative information)